# Export Angular Library as CDN package

Tags: html, angular, cdn, angular-library

I know how to create Angular Libray and include it as using install .taz file in angular application.

But i need to create library as package and include in my another application, may be ( simple HTML Application ) or may be in ( Angualr Application ) as CDN.

So that we can deploy libray and include library as CDN in another project.